# Что делают на фуникулёре при перемещении

Tags: грамотная-речь

Допустимо ли сочетание "ездить на фуникулёре"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Основная функция фуникулера - перемещение вверх/вниз. Поэтому по отношению к нему более корректно употребление глаголов "подниматься/спускаться".

Глагол "ездить", как и по отношению к слову "лифт", возможен, но будет нести оттенок разговорного стиля. "Я ездил на лифте" - такую фразу легче представить в речи деревенского жителя, впервые воспользовавшегося лифтом.

Поскольку фуникулер часто используют в целях наслаждения открывающимися видами, то довольно часто используют глагол "кататься/прокатиться" на фуникулере.

Comment: А если движение регулярное? Наверху - ресторан, я тут ездил на фуникулере. И что вы будете делать со своими "более корректными" вариантами?

Answer (score 1):

***На фуникулере*** ездят примерно так же, как и ***на лифте*** (а также на многих других подобных средствах перевозки).
При этом на фуникулере можно не только ***ездить***, но и ***подниматься***/***спускаться***.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, употребление глагола несовершенного вида "**ездить**" в отношении фуникулёра или эскалатора ограничивается случаями **регулярного** пользования этими средствами. Например, так можно сказать о сотруднике метрополитена (напр. об уборщице), который *в течение рабочего дня* ездит на эскалаторе с одного уровня на другой (но едва ли пассажир "*ездит* на эскалаторе", хотя вполне может "**ехать**" в какой-то момент своей поездки в метро), или о работнике комплекса Ниагарского водопада, который "**ездит на фуникулёре**" на работу, если он живёт вблизи его верхней станции. О туристах, остановившихся на день-два в отеле там же, наверху, лучше сказать "**поднимаются**" или "**спускаются**" (либо *едут* - если в данный момент).

Answer (score 1):

Едут на нем. И ездят тоже. В зависимости от контекста.
Глаголы ехать-ездить образуют пару глаголов движения (см., например http://russkiyyazik.ru/178/).

Первый отвечает за однонаправленное движение, второй за все остальное. Других ограничений нет, фуникулер как транспортное средство в грамматике ничем не отличается от трамвая или самоката.

Comment: Тогда и "ездить на самолёте" возможно?

Comment: @Владимир *Тогда и "ездить на самолёте" возможно?*  Да запросто. По взлетно-посадочной. Хотя в каком-то смысле можно и по воздуху. У "ехать"/"ездить" есть еще и значение обобщенного направленного передвижения - аналог английскому "to go". И хотя в русском оно не так популярно, все-таки оно существует. "Ездил в командировки". - да запросто и на самолете.

Comment: Но у нас это даже и не требуется. Ехать можно на всем, что само по себе едет. Фуникулер-то уж точно в бытовом понимании едет, не плывет, не летит.